# When performing a soft reboot using the restart button, what should I see in my /var/log/syslog?

Tags: crash, syslog

My system seems to freeze when viewing a youtube video or sometimes just using firefox, but seems to be graphic related somehow not sure.

When I click the restart button on my desktop, what should I be seeing in my /var/log/syslog file so I can maybe see what was happening before that event that froze my system?

It is getting very annoying and I can't trust my system to be stable!

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, you should use the 'top' command. That will show you the programs that are currently using resources.